# WooCommerce SSL/HTTPS logout issue

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

Straightforward explanation is that I have a WooCommerce shop in Wordpress that I want to use SSL/HTTPS on.

I have a valid certificate that I bought and HTTPS works in the various shop pages like My Account etc.

Trouble is, when one leaves the HTTPS pages and return to the main site (HTTP) I get logged out of Wordpress.

I'm using CloudFlare too by the way. Does anyone have any insight ?

I've tried searching the net for answers but got nowhere so far. Clearing cookies out and starting fresh did not help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix.

If like me you are using a certificate and HTTPS for the secure shop sections, then if you enable SSL login for the admin panel it will keep you logged in.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL